# Combination of two strings

Tags: c, recursion

I'm doing C course on my university, and i think that i'm still stuck on JAVA, because i can't get the next code (Recursion):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define N 11

int Combination(char *, char *, char *);
void main(){
int i;
char *S1[]={"","abc","abc","abc","abc","ab c","morning Venm","ABZ","12189","12189",      
    "TTTT"},

     *S2[]={"", "", "def", "def", "def", "def", "Good ita!", "ABAXZ", "129", "129", 
     "X"},

     *S3[]={"", "abc", "abcdef", "daebcf", "adfbce", "deab cf","Good morning Vietnam!",
            "ABAXABZZ", "12181299", "12112998", "XXXXX"};

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    if(Combination(S1[i],S2[i],S3[i])) 
         printf("S1: \"%s\", S2: \"%s\", S3: \"%s\", 
         Combination!\n",S1[i],S2[i],S3[i]);
    else printf("S1: \"%s\", S2: \"%s\", S3: \"%s\", Not a 
         Combination!\n",S1[i],S2[i],S3[i]);

}

_getch();
}

/*Function name : Combination
  Input : address of three strings
  Output : true(1) if the third string is a combination of the two firsts strings,    
          false (0) if not
  Algorithm : check if the third string is made from the letters of the first and  
              second strings*/
int Combination(char *S1, char *S2, char *S3)
{
    if(!*S1 && !*S2 && !*S3) return 1;
    if(*S3==*S1 && *S3==*S2)
        return (Combination(S1+1,S2,S3+1)||Combination(S1,S2+1,S3+1));
    if(*S3==*S1) return Combination(S1+1,S2,S3+1);
    if(*S3==*S2) return Combination(S1,S2+1,S3+1);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to understand any line on the Combination method.

1) if(!*S1 && !*S2 && !*S3)  = that check if the 3 Strings are null ?

2) what the part of: (S1+1,S2,S3+1) - what that doing? S1+1 will give us the next word on the array or it will give the next letter ? if it will give us the next letter - for what? it's already cheked if the strings are equal?

I'm confused...

- I got the recursion, but not the part of S1+1\S2+1\S3+1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*S1 is the first character of string S1, so

```
if (!*S1 && !*S2 && !*S3)
```

is checking to see if the first character of all three strings is null, which means they are all empty strings.

S1+1 is effectively string S1 with the first character removed.  Strings are passed around in C by passing a pointer to the first character.  By passing S1+1, the beginning of the string is moved down one character.

Comment: I think you solved my problem. because i was sure that *S1 = the word of S1[N]. but if i understand right - S[N] ---> *S1 = the first letter of S[N] ? OK... now i will looking again on the code.

Comment: The other answers not contradiction yours? (your answer look like the right because to method working.)

Comment: @Bside: It's a bit confusing because S1 is used in two different ways.  Inside main(), S1 is an array of strings, but inside Combination(), S1 is a single string.

Answer (score 0):

As to part 2), S1 + 1 will give you the address of the next string, not the next character.  The next char would be (*S1) + 1.

Comment: If i understand you - so your answer in contradiction to the answer of @Vaughn Cato

Comment: `The next char would be (*S1) + 1.` This is incorrect. *(S+1) will give the next char whereas (*S)+1 will add `1` to the char. For example, if S is "axz" then *S+1 will be 'b'.

Comment: Apologies KingsIndian, I was referring to the convention that was proposed in the first section of code, where S1 is an array of char *.  You're correct if you're referring to S1 as a char *.

Bside, our answers are not in contradiction if you take into account the different conventions that exist in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!*S1)
```

Check if `S1` is an empty C-string.

```
S1+1
```

Kind of substring of `S1`. If `S1` is a pointer to `"abc"` then `S1+1` is a pointer to `"bc"`.

Edit:
That's assuming that `S1` is a pointer to `char`, like the argument passed to the `Combination` function:

```
...(char *S1, ...
```

Some of the other answers seem to assume that `S1` is an array of pointers to `char`, like in your `main` function:

```
char *S1[] = ...
```

You probably should give them different names.

Answer (score 0):

**1) if(!*S1 && !*S2 && !*S3) = that check if the 3 Strings are null ?**

It is used to check whether all the character pointers comes to the end of string (i.e) null or not. If all reaches end it returns 1.

**2) what the part of: (S1+1,S2,S3+1) - what that doing? S1+1 will give us the next word on the array or it will give the next letter ?**

It will give us the next character.

**if it will give us the next letter - for what? it's already cheked if the strings are equal?**

To check combination for next characters.